# How to get index in pagination vuejs?

Tags: php, jquery, pagination, vue.js

I'm trying pagination in vuejs & [My code in fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/badvz/xakvbzur/12/)

```
v-for="(number, item) in items | filterBy name in 'name' | limitBy count offset"
```

my quetion is how can get index in pagination?

for example :
I have data in paging or page one :

> index :"1" - Kathy Sparks
>
> index :"2" - Gladys Tate

and then if I'm click paging two, I want to index continue

> index : 3 - Shannon
>
> index : 4 - Rosetta Scott

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest putting the output of each item into a child component and passing the index of that item in the array as a param. There are other ways to do it, such as passing the item from your vue template into a method and looking up the index of the field, eg:

```
// vue template
{{ whatIndex(item) }}

// vue js
vue.methods.whatIndex = function (item) { 
  // some logic to lookup the name from this.items
  return i
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Fastest way:

```
{{number + offset + 1}} - {{item.name}}
```